# Continuously prompt for a number until the value falls in a range

Tags: java

I have some code that asks for the number of guests for an upcoming party and returns the number of guests. I am supposed to edit this to make it continuously prompt for the number of guests until the value falls between 5 and 100 inclusive.

This is my current method to get the number of guests.

```
public static int getNumberOfGuests()
{
    Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of guests >> ");
    return inputDevice.nextInt();
}
```

I am very new and trying my best to understand. I am not sure what loop I should use that will still allow the number of guests to be returned.

Comment: Hint: You can use a `do..while` loop

Comment: You return only when you get a valid input. That's how you ensure it.... Now, please [edit] your question to include your attempts at making a loop

Comment: You'll **always** be able to return the number of guests no matter what type of loop you choose.  So just pick whichever way you're most comfortable with.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a do..while loop. I had tried doing that originally but was writing it wrong.

Comment: This is what I wrote and it ended up working.                                                 
    public static int getNumberOfGuests()
    {
        int var;
        do
        {Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of guests >> ");
        var = inputDevice.nextInt();
        }while(var < 5 || var > 100);

        return var;

Comment: @Jay you should handle Scanner out of getNumberOfGuest scope (pass it through parameters). Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

as @user7 mention, you can use a [do-while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) iteration to make an "until decision".

Why `do-while` and not regular `while`? Because it is going to execute the first iteration before check the expression to continue.

According to your example, the code would be:

### getNumberOfGuests:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestGetNumGuest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
        getNumberOfGuests(inputDevice);
        System.out.println("ended");
        getNumberOfGuests(inputDevice);
        System.out.println("ended");
        inputDevice.close();
    }
    
    public static int getNumberOfGuests( Scanner inputDevice)
    {
        int numGuests;
        
        do{
            System.out.print("Please enter the number of guests >> ");
            numGuests = inputDevice.nextInt();

        }while(numGuests < 5 || numGuests > 100);
        return numGuests;
    }

}
```

**P.S** `Scanner` is handled out of `getNumberOfGuests()` because it should be closed, but if you close it inside the method you won't be able to call more than once.

### Example I/O:

```
Please enter the number of guests >> 1
Please enter the number of guests >> 2
Please enter the number of guests >> 3
Please enter the number of guests >> 4
Please enter the number of guests >> 6
ended
Please enter the number of guests >> 1
Please enter the number of guests >> 2
Please enter the number of guests >> 3
Please enter the number of guests >> 101
Please enter the number of guests >> 100
ended
```

Comment: Don't need to instantiate a `Scanner` per input, do it outside the loop. FYI: you probably should not close that `Scanner`, you won't be able to call `getNumberOfGuests` again !

Comment: @AxelH Thanks for pointing that out. I just edited the answer, so Scanner is handled out of method scope (it should be closed, but not inside).

Answer (score 0):

A simple do-while or while loop will do the job:

```
class Demo{

    public static void main(String[]args){
        try(java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in)){
            System.out.printf("No. of guest: %d%n", getNumberOfGuests(sc,5,100));
            System.out.printf("No. of guest: %d%n", getNumberOfGuests(sc,10,19));
        }
    }

    public static int getNumberOfGuests(final java.util.Scanner sc, final int min, final int max) {
        int guest = -1;
        do{
            System.out.printf("Please enter no. of guest (%d to %d): ", min, max);
            if(sc.hasNextInt()){
                guest = sc.nextInt();
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Kindly input numbers only!");
            sc.nextLine();
        }while(min > guest || max < guest);
        return guest;
    }
}
```

[image: output]